# add a dummy instruction to the binary file in cuda

Tags: assembly, cuda

I am trying to mark a region of the code in CUDA files and then simulate it in GPGPU-Sim (a popular simulator for CUDA codes). I would like to add a dummy instruction to the CUDA and then capture it in the simulator. I have done that before in X86 instruction set, but it is not working the same way here. The way that I accomplished this in X86 is by adding an inline assembly code to the .C file like the following:

```
  __asm__ __volatile__ (".byte 0x60;\n")
```

This will introduce a "bad" instruction in the assembly code. I am trying to add such a "bad" instruction to the CUDA files. Is there any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly have you tried, and what were the results? One difference between `as` and `pxtas` is that the latter is a compiler, not just an assembler. It performs dead-code elimination, for example. The other difference is that `0x60` probably maps to a valid x86 instruction (I haven't checked), but it definitely is not a valid instruction for the GPU, whose instructions are typically 8 bytes in length. I am not sure whether CUDA's inline PTX support allows `.byte` as part of the code. I know I have inserted markers using inline PTX before, but I can't recall what rare instruction I used.

Comment: @njuffa Thanks. I am only trying to add some markers around some of the instructions. Something like "nop" instructions so I can detect it in the simulator.

Comment: You could try exactly that: insert a no-op instruction via inline PTX and then compile with -Xptxas -O0 to disable `ptxas` optimizations. I am not sure whether that will preserve the no-op instruction. As part of code optimization `ptxas` will otherwise remove all dead code, in particular instructions without data dependencies, and it will also change the order of instructions when doing instruction scheduling. This makes it difficult to add markers to machine code. As a compiler, `ptxas` doesn't provide the level of control that the assembler `as` on the CPU gives you.

Comment: The problem with no-op is that the compiler might also insert some no-op in the code. Then it would be impossible to detect whether it is the no-op that compiler inserted or it is the one that I inserted. I think you can have "asm volatile" to enforce compiler not to optimize it away. right?

Comment: As I recall the PTX instruction set does not actually offer a `nop` instruction per se. You would have to use an instruction that does nothing but is unlikely to be generated by the compiler or used much by programmers. Something like `usad %0, %0, %0, %0`. I am not sure you can do much better than that from PTX-level, at least I cannot think of anything right now. I do not know what guarantees the compiler gives with regard to "asm volatile".

Comment: The PTX instruction pmevent.mask can be inserted with inline assembly. This instruction takes a 16-bit immediate so you have 2^16 encoding you can detect. This instruction is a variant of no-op that drives 16-bits to the pmsystem. Some of the profilers use this instruction but it is not generated by the compiler. The compiler may move the instruction but it should never eliminate the instruction. See [PTX ISA pmevent](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#miscellaneous-instructions-pmevent) for more information.

Comment: @GregSmith Thanks a lot for your response. I think it could lead me to a solution. I might be able to enforce the compiler not to move it by using asm volatile as explained here [link](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/inline-ptx-assembly/index.html#incorrect-optimization).